# Follow me for WordPress blogs (multi-authors)

Tags: customization, users

If we have a blog with multiple authors is there a way for each to have a "follow me" twitter button separated. Meaning when we see the post of an author we see only the twitter button with the author account. Or because is a one blog the only option is a Follow us button meaning one account for all the authors?

Comment: it would be nice if you can put "follow author name" - cuz ppl could mis-understand between following the whole blog or each specific author (the last option being less widespread" )

Comment: Yeah. I want to do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a follow button plugin like the one in my [Simple Twitter Connect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-twitter-connect/) plugin, then you should be able to specify the user you want the button to be for.

So for example, with STC, I'd activate STC-Login and the STC-Follow Button Widget plugins. Then I'd have my users "connect" their twitter accounts and their WP accounts (STC-Login lets them do this on the Users->Your Profile page). That way it knows what their twitter accounts are.

Then this code in a theme should do the trick:

```
$twuid = get_the_author_meta('twuid');
if ( !empty($twuid) && function_exists('stc_follow_button') ) {
  stc_follow_button($twuid);
}
```

You'll have to put that code into the Loop or somewhere after it, so that the get_the_author_meta() function knows what user to look for.

Comment: how can extend this idea in a more generic form like for the "follow us" module that I am using on my website thelazy.info .